# Cant install Qbittorent in Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Tags: ppa, repository, qbittorrent

I added the PPA using this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
```

I entered the password and hit enter.

In the 13th process, I encountered this error:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
```

I also encountered:

```
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
```

I think this has to do with the version of Ubuntu that I am using, (ubuntu focal 20.04), in the end, there was this message:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should I do?

I can't post the full process as it has too many links.

Comment: Why not just install from Ubuntu.  Qbittorrent is available in software store,  don't need a ppa.  The errors look like the ppa has not been updated for 20.04.

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources, so all checks (are they good for your release, can they be trusted, are they maintained & supported) are all on you.  Did you check?  That PPA ended support in 2018 (18.10); you're using a 2020-April release so it's of course not supported...

Comment: aaw thanks man, I'm really new in all this universe its like speaking other language hihi, thanki u :)

Comment: @crip659 I don't understand, the Ubuntu store ? I don't find there ithink

Comment: really thanks ingoing to search here